# Connecting to an Sqlite3 database with Haskell / Persistent

Tags: haskell, sqlite, libraries, hackage

Please forgive how simple this question is.

Google searches, [the documentation](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/persistent), and [the Yesod book](http://www.yesodweb.com/book/persistent) seem to only explain how to do things *with* databases, but I have yet to see a straight forward explanation on how to actually *connect* to one.

Any help or guidance in the right direction would be appreciated.

**Edit**: I [simplified the code sample](http://subtlearray.tumblr.com/post/43845818836) from the Yesod book to make it a little easier to read and use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "Home Page" of the persistent package has an example showing how to connect to an in-memory instance of sqlite:

http://www.yesodweb.com/book/persistent

Seems that all you would have to change is the `withSqliteConn` call.

Comment: I see. So withSqliteConn is like connectSqlite3 from HDBC (Database.HDBC.Sqlite3). It makes sense now. Thank you.